# How to get the selected data sent back to SF record in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

The following code allows a person to choose seminars to attend for a specific program they have signed up for. How to send their choice(s) back to the personID record in SF assuming that the same fields names are on that record. (I included the VF code but it doesn't seem to show in the preview of the question so I am not sure if it'll show in the actual question. Anyone know why this keeps happening?)

**VF page:**

```
 <apex:PageBlock title="Choose Your Preferred Seminar(s) for ">  <apex:form title="{!progName}">
       <apex:selectList value="{!names}" multiselect="false">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectList>  </apex:form>   </apex:PageBlock>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class sampleCon {
public String getItems { get; set; }
public String progName { get; set; }    
public List<Program__c> availableAccountsList { get; set; }

public String[] names = new String[10];
String personID = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('personId');        
String programID = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('pId');    


public String[] getnames() 
{
    return names;
}

public void setnames(String[] names) 
{
    this.names = names;
}
public  List<SelectOption> getItems() {
         availableAccountsList = [Select Name,Seminar1__r.Name,Seminar2__r.Name,Seminar3__r.Name,Seminar4__r.Name,Seminar5__r.Name,Seminar6__r.Name,Seminar7__r.Name,Seminar8__r.Name,Seminar9__r.Name,Seminar10__r.Name,Seminar11__r.Name
                                From Program__c
                                Where ID = :programID
                                ];
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Name != Null) progName = availableAccountsList[0].Name;

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar1__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar1__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar1__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar2__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar2__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar2__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar3__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar3__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar3__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar4__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar4__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar4__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar5__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar5__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar5__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar6__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar6__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar6__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar7__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar7__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar7__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar8__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar8__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar8__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar9__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar9__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar9__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar10__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar10__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar10__r.Name));
        if(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar11__c != Null) options.add(new SelectOption(availableAccountsList[0].Seminar11__r.Name,availableAccountsList[0].Seminar11__r.Name));

         return options;

}
```

}

Comment: In edit mode, you need to select the Visualforce or Apex and use the {} button to format them.

Comment: Keith, I did that numerous times. I need to put come tags on the same line otherwise it cuts off when there is a new line in the VF but it doesn't do this in the controller code.